# Conditional Formatting to reflect Countifs

Tags: excel, excel-2010, countif

I am using Excel2010 and I have the following Countifs statement, which works.

```
=COUNTIFS(Apr2014Fixed!$T:$T,"1",Apr2014Fixed!$Q:$Q,"*No*",Apr2014Fixed!$R:$R,"*Yes*")
```

I want to see which rows in my spreadsheet were counted, so that I can determine whether I've done everything right. I tried conditional formatting with the following formula, but I know I'm not using it properly.

```
=AND(COUNTIFS(Apr2014Fixed!$T:$T,"1",Apr2014Fixed!$Q:$Q,"*No*",Apr2014Fixed!$R:$R,"*Yes*")=3)
```

I don't understand what value I am looking to highlight. I thought =3 because I want all three conditions to be true for a case to be counted, but this didn't highlight anything. When I tried >3, it highlighted the entire spreadsheet.

Obviously, I have no idea how this works? Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Are you planning to do this in R?

Comment: I think r was a mistake as docendo suggests but I added the `excel` tag for now. Please remove the `r` tag if it is not an `r-language` related problem.

Comment: I assume the formatting needs to be in the same sheet as the data (Apr2014Fixed), is that right? Are you trying to conditionally format only within a single column or multiple columns for the rows which satisfy the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

To format rows across multiple columns, select the desired columns (in the screenshot I selected Q to T) and create a new conditional format with the formula

```
=AND($T1=1,ISNUMBER(FIND("No",$Q1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Yes",$R1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @teylyn. My colleague says I should send you a gift and I definitely would if I could. This is the solution and I was struggling so much before this. I am incredibly grateful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Your gift could be a few reputation points. Mark as the answer and upvote.